# jQuery/Multiselect plugin: How to get selected items array with click/checkAll events?

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I am able to get the array of all selected values when using the single 'click' event. As soon as I click to check/uncheck an element I get either a null back or 'undefined'.
Here is a snipset of the code:

```
    $("#Status").multiselect
    ({
        noneSelectedText: "Select Status",
        selectedList: 3,
        multiple: true,
        click: function (event, ui) {
            var values1 = $(this).val();
            alert(values1); //returns null or undefined for single clicks
        },
        checkAll: function (event, ui) {
            var values2 = $(this).val();
            alert(values2); //returns all selected elements A,B,C,D etc...
        }
    })
    .multiselectfilter
    ({
        width: 100
    });
```

Any ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I finally found what I needed, here it is:

```
var array_of_checked_values = $("#FilterStatus").multiselect("getChecked").
                             map(function () {
                                return this.value;
                             }).get();
```